# How to work with stored procedures in EF 6 and MVC 5 using code first

Tags: ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Explain these:
1.Can we use stored procedure in MVC (using code first) simmilar to Web Form?
2.How to call stored procedures without mapping or designer files?

Answer (score -1):

To quote someone else here on stackoverflow:

`this.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityType>("storedProcedureName",params);`